# Is there a way to execute a glue job via API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, aws-glue

I want to know that is there any way to execute an AWS Glue Job (Python shell type) **directly** via API Gateway.
My Glue job reads a file from the AWS S3 bucket and does an operation using the file content. I have already created the python script in the AWS glue job and it is run successfully. I want to execute the Glue Job via API Gateway.

Is it possible to do so?

Can you please give me a hint to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest would be to start it from lambda: api gateway->lambda->glue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. If you don't mind can you explain how should i invoke a lambda through api? I hope it involves using get method

Comment: I added answer with some more details and links.

Comment: Is there any direct method to do this? Coz I want a direct method

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 3):

You can setup [Lambda Proxy Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) for the API gateway. The integration is the easiest and the recommended way of invoking lambda using API gateway.

So the only thing you need to do is basically to write your lambda that starts the glue job. You can also return some useful information to the end user through the api gateway. Maybe Glue job id or something like this.

Good tutorial explaining how to create the Lambda integration is here;

- [TUTORIAL: Build a Hello World API with Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I want a direct method of doing that. If you have any idea of doing that please let me know!

Comment: @Upz You can use `AWS` integration. But this will be a bit of exercise to setup. Example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html).

Comment: @Marcin is there any direct way to start glue job by using rest API gateway without using any lambda functions

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to invoke any AWS API in API Gateway via the AWS Proxy mechanism.

Building from what Marcin pointed you at, [click here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html) for a guide about the general ability to invoke AWS APIs via API Gateway

Specifically, you are going to want to target the [StartJobRun](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-runs.html#aws-glue-api-jobs-runs-StartJobRun) action of the Glue Jobs API

Basically, you need to read the documentation to understand how AWS's StartJobRun REST API is invoked and pass that payload to your API Gateway and the API Gateway will happily forward the request to their own Glue Jobs REST API.

The upside to this is you have a direct integration without needing other infrastructure and the latency that comes with jumps through those additional hoops.

The downside is you have no control over the input/output to/from your API and you have to pass exactly what AWS wants you to pass to invoke their own REST APIs.  Also, I personally find AWS's REST API documentation much more difficult to understand and more difficult to use than their Python and Node SDKs.  That is why many folks create a simple lambda component in between the two services so they can define the request and response formats (which you can make very simple for clients) and you can use an SDK you are already familiar.